# Why does the first of these two replacements fail to take effect?

Tags: sqlite

Why does

```
UPDATE Playlists 
SET PlaylistName = replace(PlaylistName,'TDJ','TDJe'),
PlaylistName = replace(PlaylistName,'TDJe','TDJxxx')
```

fail to make the replacement of TDJ?

And what's a good compact fix, considering I might want many replacements?

Answer (score 0):

In an UPDATE statement, any occurence of a column value (such as `PlaylistName`) on the right side of the `=` has the *original* value.
It is the equivalent of the following imperative code:

```py
for each row:
    old = playlistName
    new1 = replace(old,'TDJ','TDJe')
    new2 = replace(old,'TDJe','TDJxxx')
    playlistName = new1
    playlistName = new2
```

It never makes sense to try to update a column twice.

You have to make all replacements within a single expression:

```
UPDATE Playlists
SET PlaylistName = replace(replace(PlaylistName, 'TDJ', 'TDJe'), 'TDJe', 'TDJxxx')
```

Comment: "any occurence of a column value (such as PlaylistName) on the right side of the = has the original value." I expect that. "It never makes sense to try to update a column twice." What's against my two replacements acting on the original?